# image scale in android using OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm using opengl to render an image as texture.I want to zoom the texture,so i use ScaleGestureDetector.
Here is my code:

```
public void scale(float scale, float focusX, float focusY) {
    Matrix.setIdentityM(uMVPMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(uMVPMatrix, 0, focusX, focusY, 0f);
    Matrix.scaleM(uMVPMatrix, 0, scale, scale, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(uMVPMatrix, 0, -focusX, -focusY, 0f);
}


private float scale = 1f;
private float focusX;
private float focusY;
@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    renderer.scale(detector.getScaleFactor() * scale,focusX,focusY);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    focusX = (detector.getFocusX() - ScreenDimensionHelper.getScreenWidth(context)/2) / ((float) ScreenDimensionHelper.getScreenWidth(context)/2);
    focusY = (ScreenDimensionHelper.getScreenHeight(context)/2- detector.getFocusY()) / ((float) ScreenDimensionHelper.getScreenHeight(context)/2);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    this.scale = detector.getScaleFactor() * scale;
}
```

I want to zoom around the position where my finger touch.But I found that while I pinch the image,the image moves as well.Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: I think your translate logic should be the other way around. First translate by -focusX/Y, then translate back by +focusX/Y

Comment: I don't this so.[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517799/scaling-around-point-pinch-zoom-with-android-and-opengl-es-2-0)

Comment: @GilMoshayof I believe the `Matrix` utility class behaves similarly to the legacy fixed pipeline, where the transformation you specify last is applied first. Couldn't hurt swapping it, and see what happens, but I suspect that this order is correct. Hard to tell what the problem is just from looking at it. I would run this in a debugger (or add logging), and see if all the values are as expected. Is this the only transformation you are using, or are you applying other transformations before/after this one?

Comment: @RetoKoradi.Yes! I just want to zoom the texture using `ScaleGestureDetector`.Here is my code.[github](https://github.com/nhsprite/OpenGL).I have been working on this some days...thanks for your attention!